# Trying to Convert .netBrowser Post Request to Cefsharp Chromium

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I trying to convert .NET Browser request method on my source code to cefsharp Chromium but I have a big problem :( 
`Cefsharp` `LoadUrlWithPostData` is not working like this :( 
I have so many post requests in my code what is simple method for `cefsharp` I need change PostRequest codes for `cefsharp`

This is the original working `.netBrowser` PostRequest method

```
private void PostRequest(Uri p_Uri, NameValueCollection p_PostData)
{
    try
    {
        m_HttpHandler.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        m_HttpHandler.UploadValuesAsync(p_Uri, p_PostData);
        m_HttpHandler.Headers.Remove("X-Requested-With");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteExceptionToLog(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

.NetBrowser Post Request Example;

```
private void UpdateCollectDataRequest()
{
    try
    {
         var l_Url = "https://" + Settings.MainUrl + "/collect/data?data_id=" + Data3 +
                    "&action=get&h=" + H;

        PostRequest(new Uri(l_Url), new NameValueCollection() { { "json", "{\"types\":[{\"type\":\"map\",\"param\":{\"x\":7,\"y\":5}},{\"type\":\"bar\"},{\"type\":\"backbone\"}],\"data_id\":" + Data3 + ",\"nl_init\":false}" } });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteExceptionToLog(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me ? How can I do this with CefSharp

Comment: `LoadUrlWithPostData` is just an extension method, you can look at the source and modify it to your needs. Make sure you read http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_LoadUrlWithPostData.htm in detail. See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2705

Comment: @amaitland Can you give an example me :( i am  newbie and trying to learn programming

Comment: The source is https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/73/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L356 At least have a go at implementing it yourself.